# Avoid recursive dupes in review queue

Tags: discussion, review, duplicate-questions

I've just come to this review:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/39952

The question suggested as the *duplicate* is already closed as a duplicate of the question in the review queue.

I presume the question proposed as the duplicate was itself marked as dupe of the question in the review queue *after* the flag was raised on the question in the review.

---

In the interest of science, I clicked "close as dupe" to see if the site would allow me to create a dupe loop in the review area.

However, clever site, simply told me:

> This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only
>   leading in a circle.

Both "Edit" and "Skip" are essentially pointless as I'll just be leaving the review there for someone else to clean up, or the close votes to eventually time out.
"Leave Open" is the only possible option to clean up this review.

### Solution

When a question is being flagged as a duplicate, check if the question being proposed as the duped question is not already in a review queue with the question being flagged as a proposed duplicate.

So:
QuestionA is flagged as a dupe of QuestionB.
If QuestionB is already in an an active review queue as being a dupe of QuestionA, don't allow the flag on QuestionA until the review is completed.

This makes sense because it resolves the issue of a review queue obtaining a potentially recursive review.
And allows the first flagged question to be fully reviewed.

In the review I saw this scenario in, the question flagged first seems to have been reviewed last.
If community decides the first question flagged is a dupe, then so be it. No need for a war. In fact, the same user(s) who do not remember the two questions might vote to close *both* as a dupe for each other, until the final vote, then the question remaining in the review queue can only be "Left Open".

---

I recognise it's probs not worthwhile to think about all this and write code for it, when it'll likely be a rare occurrence.
Just making it known for discussion, and more-so for the site devs to be aware of it (who, to be fair, will likely start singing "things that make you go *meh*" :D).